# Custom .formLogin() Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf, spring-security

I am trying to use my page created to authenticate, it is the login.jsf. I use in .loginPage `/ login.jsf` with 2 inputs and 1 button to authenticate. However, by filling in the logins and password fields, and clicking the button, nothing happens. Unlike Spring Security own `.formLogin()` itself, which already does all the processing by clicking the button.

**My method**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login.jsf").anonymous()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login.jsf")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.jsf")
      .failureUrl("/login.jsf?error=true")
      .and()
      .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsf");
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Print screen default .formLogin()

[image]

Comment: What's the request url when you submit the form ?

Comment: @Juan Is login.html, the login.html form opens normal. But clicking "Login" does not process, just the .formLogin () that is default to Spring.

Comment: Mixing Spring-mvc and JSF is error-prone

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following article from spring security documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#creating-a-login-view

Quoting the article,

> The URL we submit our username and password to is the same URL as our
>   login form (i.e. /login), but a POST instead of a GET.

So I believe you have to make a POST call to the /login endpoint with your authentication details for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Even using the .loginPage ("/ login") of error 404.

Comment: Handling POST requests for login is not required when using Spring Security's in-built login handler. Only the GET request needs to be handled to serve the proper page when its URL is accessed. The POST request, and subsequent authentication, is handled internally by Spring using the configuration @Diego Gean da Fé is specifying using `.formLogin()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use file extensions when specifying pages in the configuration. The `ViewResolver` will take care of it. Simply specify

```
 .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage")
 .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
 .and()
 .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");`
```

And make sure a ViewResolver is configured to append `.jsf` to the url. The DispatcherServlet will take care of locating the appropriate page.

Also, not to mention, you should have controllers with the appropriate `@RequestMapping`s defined to handle your requests.